# react-leaflet mouseover/out event and redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-leaflet

I am trying to add mouseover/out events to a `<GeoJSON />` component of `react-leaflet`.
If I am adding the events like in the code snippet below and **only** add the `console.log()` everything is working fine (mouseover and mouseout are working).

But i added a redux action (`this.props.hoverQuickInfo`) to update the css class of an element. Now i can only register mouseover, but mouseout is never called. I tried it without redux and I was using the `setState` having the same result.

```
onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        'mouseover': (e) => {
            console.log('over!');
            // this.setState({show: true});
            this.props.hoverQuickInfo(true);
        },
        'mouseout': (e) => {
            console.log('out!');
            // this.setState({show: false});
            this.props.hoverQuickInfo(false);
        },
    });
}
```

I read a little bit about it and found that a redux state change will result in a call of `shouldComponentUpdate` where I tried to 'filter' out any updates to the 'same' GeoJSON element, but i could not figure out how to get it to work and why it happens.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.ui.showQuickInfo) {
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Maybe someone out there is able to help me.

Comment: are you sure `mouseover` is called ?

Comment: Yes. `console.log` is working for mouseover/mouseout, but **only** if there is **no** `setState` or redux action attached to it. With `setState` or redux action added it only `console.log`s mouseover.

Comment: This seems problematic at a couple levels.  First, you probably shouldn't be trying to go through Redux _just_ to change a CSS class.  Second, I'm not sure _how_ you're trying to get that change to happen.  Third, `shouldComponentUpdate` will only run when your `mapState` function returns different values than before.  Can you give some more info on how you're trying to do things right now?

Comment: I suspect scope issues ? The code is pretty simple and should work, actually it works with console.log . dunno. try not to use `this` or write separate functions for mouseover and mouseout

Answer (score 2):

As merkerikson mentioned, you want to be very careful that you're not re-rendering the GeoJSON whenever your redux store changes.  If that happens, react-leaflet could end up rendering an entirely new GeoJSON leaflet instance that is no longer listening for a mouseover on the previous GeoJSON instance.

Also, in your `shouldComponentUpdate` you are referencing `this.props` which is going to be the old props.  You need to change that to use the `nextProps` argument.

Furthermore, react-leaflet allows you to define the listeners on the GeoJSON component itself.  Try rewriting your component to look more like this:

```
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {

  onMouseOut = (e) => {
    console.log('onMouseOut', e)
  }

  onMouseOver = (e) => {
    console.log('onMouseOver', e)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Map 
        center={[51.505, -0.09]} 
        zoom={13} 
        >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        <GeoJSON
          data={polygon}
          onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut}
          onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
       />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```

See this jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/q2v7t59h/414/